# ClassNotFoundException with ServletContextlistener on Tomcat 10

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat10

I am trying to build a webapplication project using Netbeans 12.4 and Tomcat 10.0.13.
And I am surprised to see my project compile well but the context listener is never invoked. Instead I see messages like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
```

in the logs. My war does not bundle servet API and solutions as with [ClassNotFoundException with ServletContextlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849452/classnotfoundexception-with-servletcontextlistener) seem to not work, so I went another path and tried to find the ServletContextListener class in the Tomcat installation. And found it in ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib/servlet-api.jar. So far so good.

But when I inspected the jar further, the fully qualified class name is `jakarta.servlet.ServletContextListener`. Alarmed, I searched on and found https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/servletapi/index.html?jakarta/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

This does not look like a glitch, does it? But then, how am I expected to write a Java webapplication? Should I compile versus `javax.servlet.XXX` or `jakarta.servlet.XXX` ?

Comment: Tomcat 10 is JakartaEE **not** JavaEE.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Switching my project and dependencies from JavaEE to JakartaEE actually helped. It effectively means to compile versus jakarta.servlet. I was not aware about that huge breach.